# Can you disable an extension in the XML file for a specific browser?

Tags: extensions

I am having problems with Internet Explorer 7 (unfortunately 20% of our customer base still use IE 7). One of our extensions doesn't seem to be Internet Explorer 7 compatible and is mucking up the look and functionality of our configurable product pages.

Is there a way in the XML file that i can disable this extension or the JavaScript if the user is using IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes definitely, you can use conditions if your layout like this:

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>myjavascript.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
```

The if tag is what you need. lt means "less than", you can also use lte (less than/equals), gt (greather than), gte (greather than/equals).

Comment: This worked for internet Explorer however it is also removing it for chrome?

Comment: Nope it should not if you specify the if tag correctly as my example, it should only affect IE.

Comment: This is what i have ... <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/amasty/amconf/configurable.js</name><params/><if>gt IE 7</if></action> which removes the script for 7 and 6 but also on chrome, firefox and oprea

Comment: Ok so that means that the js/amasty/amconf/configurable.js will only be added for IE > 7 (so from IE8). What do you need exactly ?

Comment: that is exactly what i want, however it is affecting the other browsers as well?

Comment: No it should not affect other browsers, only IE.